# Export and Search website content on Python using dictionary

Tags: python

I need to create a python script to *make the Information available as per date*. So i have to use the date as key (Enter date and search) and rest of the information as the values (result of search).

I can make it work but I cannot figure out a way to make the date as the key.

```
webdata = open("full_blacklist_database.txt")
print (webdata)
mydict = {}

for line in webdata:
    if not line.startswith("#") and not line.startswith("\n"):  
        keyspaced, valuespaced = line.split("#")      #strip() wont remove the tabs
        key = keyspaced.strip().replace('\t',"")
        value = valuespaced.replace('\n',"")
        value2 = value.split(",")
        mydict[key] = value2
print(mydict)

searchModule(mydict)
```

Please help if possible.
(I don't really want to use JSON for this)

*Sample Line in webdata*

```
1.0.136.29           # 2018-11-12, node-1lp.pool-1-0.dynamic.totbb.net, THA, 2
```

Comment: you are currently setting the ip as the key and  values as a list of [date,link,enc,int]

you need to put the ip in the list and pop the date from the list and set it as key

Comment: try date = value2.pop(0) , value2.append(key)